# Convert string to hash with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, string, hash

I am saving one field as string in my model, so after that i tried via console

```
1.9.3-p547 :250 > s1 = s.send_details

 => "---\nnew_order: order\nprogress: order  on d way\ndelivered:\n  
message: delivered\n  send_after: '1'\n"

1.9.3-p547 :255 > JSON.parse(s1)
JSON::ParserError: 757: unexpected token at '---

'

1.9.3-p547 :262 > s1.class
=> String
```

i am trying to convert this to json or hash, because i need to take the values from that, is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can't with that string. Try too look at method before this call, and try to set `send_details` with a `json` or a `hash`, instead of parsing it afterwards.

Comment: Adding `serialize :send_details` to the model should serialize (and deserialize) the attribute automatically, see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like your string is a YAML. You can easy decode it with `YAML.load`:

```
require 'yaml'
YAML.load("---\nnew_order: order\nprogress: order  on d way\ndelivered:\n  message: delivered\n  send_after: '1'\n")
=> {"new_order"=>"order", "progress"=>"order  on d way", "delivered"=>{"message"=>"delivered", "send_after"=>"1"}}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much grych, i just want to know something, why didn't take that filed value as string, in the model the data type of that filed is text in postgresql?

Comment: Probably that field was `serializable`. That means that you can write any object you want. In database, it is coded with YAML. Try do make this field `serializable` in the model, so when you will read it, you'll get the Hash in return.

Comment: Thanks grych for the comment